# polygonize raster so that every cell becomes a polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygonize

Is there a proper way of polygonizing a continuous raster so that every cell becomes a polygon? What I do now is make the cells differ enough so that the algorithm makes different polygons of them. for example:

```
raster1 ^ 8 -> raster2
polygonize raster2 -> vector1
```

This is however not a guaranteed-to-work approach. Anyone has any ideas on a better approach?

Comment: A workaround by creating a grid and attaching values from the raster: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54362/how-to-make-polygon-from-cells-of-a-raster. OpenJUMP can convert rasters which are opened as Sextante rasters into point or polygon grid directly.